# Symfony 2 collection of forms - prototype

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I would like to use prototype like here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype, but my form looks:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-4">{{ form_widget(productAttribute.attribute, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">{{ form_widget(productAttribute.value, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}</div>
</div>
```

Before the loop is a div with data-prototype attribute which contains form fields without wrapped divs and classes and I don't know how to get wrapped divs with classes there. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Twig side:

```
<div id="template" style="display: none">
    {{ form_widget(form.tags.vars.prototype)|e }}
</div>
```

Js side:

```
var templateContent = $.("#template").html();
```

Or, twig:

```
{% set subform = form.tags.vars.prototype %} 

{{ form_row(subform.fielName) }}
...
```

Comment: You can customize your prototype by writing your own html and then escape it with htmlentities()